# How to convert the nest if to when

Tags: kotlin

If I have the following nest if else condition, how to convert it to when?

```
if (something.isNotEmpty()) {
    doSomething1()
    if (something.contains(condition1)) {
        doSomething2()
    } else if (something.contains(condition2)) {
        doSomething3()
    }
} else {
    doSomething4()
}

// when condition something like
when(something) {
    ... -> ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think converting to `when` is a good idea. why do you want it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have nested `when` statements. You can;

```
        when{
            something.isNotEmpty() -> {
                doSomething1()
                if (something.contains(condition1)){
                    doSomething2()
                }
                else if(something.contains(condition2)) {
                    doSomething3()
                }
            }
            else -> doSomething4()
        }
```

Comment: That's not doing the same as the question, though.  For example, if `condition1` is in `something`, the code in the question will call `doSomething1()` and then `doSomething2()`.  But this code would only call `doSomething1()`.  (Remember that unlike a Java `switch` statement, cases in a Kotlin `when` do *not* fall through.)

Comment: I see. I have updated the answer. But then again what's the point of switching to a when statement?

Comment: Good question!  I've seen many nested `if`s which _can_ be broken down (possibly through reordering and/or inverting tests) into a simple sequence that translates very neatly to a `when` — and it's usually worth doing so.  But here, it can't, and nested `when`s are no better than nested `if`s.  In this case, I find it clearest to split out the bits before and after calling `doSomething1()`, as in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62989785/10134209) by @Mosius.

Comment: Alternatively, I am not sure what doSomething1() is but you can have a when statement that checks the 4 conditions separately and in doSomething2() and doSomething2() you can have them call doSomething1() as the first thing.

Comment: Oh, indeed.  So yes, technically you _can_ do it all in one `when`.  But that sort of duplication smells of cut-and-paste programming (with the corresponding impact on readability and maintainability, especially if it's more than one or two lines).

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't do the whole logic in one `when`, I recommend not to make things nested which make it hard to read, but use a more flat approach:

```kotlin
if (!something.isNotEmpty()) { // or something.isEmpty()
    doSomething4()
    return
}

doSomething1()

when {
    something.contains(condition1) -> doSomething2()
    something.contains(condition2) -> doSomething3()
}
```

Comment: You should add an else statement to make it exhaustive. You can only ignore the else bit if the when is a sealed class or an enum according to the documentation.

Comment: @EvansChepsiror according to documentation the `else` branch is mandatory when you use the `when` as an expression, which is not applicable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
when {
    something.isNotEmpty() -> {
        doSomething1()
        when {
            something.contains(condition1) -> doSomething2()
            something.contains(condition2) -> doSomething3()
        }
    }
    else -> doSomething4()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the other answers, a better approach would be to put the `if` condition into the `when` condition in order to preserve the logic as it is.

The code will look like:

```
when(something.isNotEmpty) {
  true -> {
    doSomething1()
    when {
      something.contains(condition1) -> doSomething2()
      something.contains(condition2) -> doSomething3()
    }
  }
  false -> doSomething4()
}
```